# Can reference and the variable it is pointing to have different values?

Tags: c++, casting, reference, constants

I could not understand why in below code snippet reference and its associated variable are giving different results.

```
const int x = 10;
const int &ptr = x; 
int& y = const_cast<int&>(ptr);
y = 19;
std::cout << "x = " << x << " ptr=" << ptr << " y=" << y << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
x=10 ptr=19 y=19
```

As per my understanding references are just alias for variable so why `ptr` is `19` and `x` is `10`? Is this something to do with `const` or `const_cast` ?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Your fridge may explode as likely as you're getting that result.

Comment: When you modify a constant value, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From *5.2.11 Const cast [expr.const.cast]*:

> Note: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer
>   to data member resulting from a `const_cast` that casts away a const-qualifier may produce undefined
>   behavior (7.1.6.1). — end note ]

You're performing undefined behavior, so you're quite (un)lucky that your computer didn't implode. :)

Comment: @Humam Because everyone wants to have their computer broken?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I guess it depends on if you're the developer or the user. :) If I were a user whose software didn't work because dev relied on UB, I might hope his computer imploded, too.

Comment: @LogicStuff imploding is better than uncaughted UB

Comment: @erip another perspective...

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Added a little note in there for you. ;)

Comment: @erip Thanks :) +1

Comment: @HumamHelfawi A (mis)fortune would be if the code produced results expected to the OP and they would then rely on that behavior in the future.

Comment: @LogicStuff That is the unluckiest possible situation.

Comment: I have seen computers exploding (well, sort of. Not really exploding, and not the whole computer - just some white smoke from hard drive) but I am yet to see one **imploded**.

Comment: @SergeyA It's more elusive, but scarier... I guess.

Comment: It might help to mention that something like `int x; int const & cx = x; const_cast<int &>(cx) = 19;` does not result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this something to do with `const` or `const_cast`?

Yes.

Even with `const_cast`, it's still undefined behavior to modify an object that was originally `const`. Or, in other words, it's illegal to use `const_cast` to write to a `const` object.

Comment: I know. That's why I said it's illegal to *modify* / *write*.

Comment: The way I see it is, if you did the cast but didn't do the write operation, that means the write access isn't given. So I don't see how that statement is false. It's quite possible that I was wrong though, as English is not my native language, so feel free to edit my answer any time.